# "À disposição" vs "disponível"

Tags: português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Quando queremos falar que não estou ocupado usamos qual expressão?

1. Estou livre.
2. Estou disponível
3. Estou à disposição.

Algum tem prioridade em relação a outros em alguns casos?

Comment: Estou livre e Estou disponível tem o mesmo significado. Usuaria Estou disponível em ambientes mais formais. Estou a disposição, uso mais em forma de agradecimento. Por exemplo, faço um favor, a pessoa agradece e eu respondo: Estou a disposição

Comment: @Peixoto, já agora podias ter feito o trabalho todo (edição completa e resposta formal).

Comment: Podia, mas a minha referência nesse caso era apenas pela experiência de uma falante nativo, por isso, quis ajudar logo, mas sem formalismos! A edição, depois que vi que me passei numas coisas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Estou livre** (*free*) é o menos formal e (juntamente com "não estou ocupado") o mais usado dos três.

**Estou disponível** (*available*) e também **tenho disponibilidade** podem ser usados em alguns contextos específicos, como quando discutindo horários possíveis para um compromisso. Mas o primeiro ("estou disponível") também é frequentemente usado em pt-Br com o sentido de "aberta(o) a novos relacionamentos".

**Estou à disposição** (*at your service*) é o mais formal e costuma ser usado para indicar que a pessoa tem a função de servir/ajudar, ou ainda para responder a um agradecimento.